# How to export a sharepoint recycle bin to excel file, please let me know in step by step

Tags: sharepoint-online, recycle-bin

I'm trying to search a specific file from a sharepoint recycle bin but I'm unable to find it. Can anyone please help me in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PnP PowerShell to get the report for Recycle Bin.

Here is a sample script for your reference:

```
#Get the PnP PowerShell module
##Skip this line if you already have it
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "<SiteURL>"
$Username = "<GlobalAdminAccount>"
$Password = "<Password>"
$FilePath = "C:\Temp\RecycleBin.csv"

#Connect to PnP Online
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credential $cred

#Get Recycle bin Items
Get-PnPRecycleBinItem | Select Title, ItemType, Size, ItemState, DirName, DeletedByName, DeletedDate | Export-Csv $FilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

References:
[SharePoint Online: Search Recycle Bin using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/07/sharepoint-online-search-recycle-bin-using-powershell.html) /
[PnP PowerShell overview.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thanks much I was able to get csv file and referring.

Comment: Help me in other issue as I was trying to run a script in a newly created sharepoint Teams site. I've enabled the sharepoint customize script for the specific site through online sharepoint management shell. But still i can't run the script

 We fetch the line items from 'Products' list present in the home site and we create new subsites based on the information provided in the list items using the script. if we run caml query it returns with nothing (empty array) Can you please help me on this also?

Comment: @ThariqAziz Sure but better if you post this other question in a new post, so others can look into it for you as well.

Comment: Sure thanks will do